# In reveal foundation js, on click of X, background overlay doesn't disappear

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation, zurb-reveal

On click of X (close btn), the background overlay still present.

I did following steps \

1. click on link to open reveal modal.
2. click on X to close it.

every thing is fine for the first time, but when i do the same step again

3. click again on link to open reveal modal.
4. when i click on X this time, the modal closed but overlay still present.
   And this prevent any further action on page.

One solution was to add, `closeOnBackgroundClick=true`, but i can't do this.

I tried to debug it, i found the problem is in `toggle_bg()` function, for the next time clicked, it calls `this.show(this.settings.bg)` where as it must call `this.hide(this.settings.bg)`;

The code is in https://gist.github.com/yarosla/9844359

Comment: Why are you using Reveal from Foundation 4.3.2 with Foundation 6? Why not use Reveal that ships with Foundation 6?

Comment: i am using foundation 4.3.2. not 6

Comment: Then why is the title of your question: "**ZURB FOUNDATION 6**, on click of X, background overlay doesn't disappear"? You also tagged the question with "zurb-foundation-6"

Comment: Are you able to replicate the issue in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)?